# I installed android studio using umake, but I can't find the AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, ubuntu-make

I installed android studio using umake, but I can't find the AVD Manager.

[image]

How do I get avd manager installed and working on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Directly from toolbar

Click on the second icon

[image]

2. You can also (I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1) choose `Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager`

If it doesn't work

- choose `File -> Settings`, than find `Android SDK` menu item
- click on `Launch Standalone SDK Manager
- choose `Tools -> Manage AVDs`

[image]

It seems to you downloaded broken package, or Android Studio doesn't have or recognize Android SDK path.

---

You can also do these steps:

```
umake android --remove
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Hope it help